# How can I put the title/my name in the middle of my page?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles, cv, resume

I just can't figure this one out. I'm using

```
\documentclass[margin,line,8pt]{res}
```

and want my title/name in the middle of the page.

Comment: What's your document class? Look up `\maketitle`, perhaps here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation

Comment: \documentclass[margin,line,8pt]{res} That's what I'm using.

Comment: [How to customize the title page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280/37907)

Comment: You're welcome! or check ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/latex-samples/TitlePages/titlepages.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure `res` is the best class to use? it has hardly been updated since 1989, so is mostly older than LaTeX2e.

Anyway, if I use the line you posted

```
\documentclass[margin,line,8pt]{res}
```

I get

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [8pt].
```

as the class does not have an 8pt option, however it does have a `centered` option and

```
\documentclass[margin,centered]{res}

\begin{document}
\name{my name}
\begin{resume}

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

with the name centred.